# SQLAlchemy 2: manually unexpire a row?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, asyncpg

Prerequisites:

- PostgreSQL 14
- SQLAlchemy 2.0.19
- Python 3.10
- Asyncpg 0.28.0

Please, imagine this script:

```
async with sessionmaker() as session, session.begin():
   person: Person = await session.get(Person, (person_id, ))

   print(person.age)

   try:
       async with session.begin_nested():
          person.age = -1000
          await session.flush()
   except Exception as ex:
      pass  # ignore the exception
   
   print(person.age)
```

So, in essence we're trying to:

1. Get a person with some known id.
2. Knowingly set their age to an erroneous value **inside a subtransaction** (A.K.A. "checkpoint").
3. The subtransaction fails with a check constraint violation.
4. We catch the exception, so the transaction rolls back to the moment before the checkpoint began and continues to execute.

*Expected behavior:*

5. The person is unmodified, because all the modifications were done inside the erroneous checkpoint block, so we safely read back the `person.age`.

*What actually happens:*

5. The person object becomes [expired](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.expire), suggesting the state is inconsistent between the database and the python object.

I guess SQLAlchemy doesn't support the "modifications happened inside the checkpoint" part of my reasoning, or I just understand something inherently incorrectly.

Either way, a quick fix, as I see it, would be to forcibly `unexpire` the object. Is it, at all, possible? Or maybe there is a better way?

**EDIT:**

I've found a way to `unexpire` the object:

```
state = attributes.instance_state(person)
state.expired = False
state.expired_attributes.clear()
```

But the entirety of object's fields is set to `None` by SQLAlchemy for some reason.

**Is there a way to make it NOT DO THAT?**

*P.S.* Please, do not suggest to `refresh()`, as this is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid. I use app-level locks to ensure that nobody else accesses this precise piece of data - `refresh`ing it would defeat the whole purpose.

Comment: I can't seem to recreate the exact problem when using async.  Do you have `expire_on_commit` set to `False`?

Comment: I was able to create a "problem" though but the exception is about "greenlet_spawn has not been called".

Comment: @IanWilson this is because sqlalchemy wants to do explicit IO. The fields are expired, so when you access the field, it spawns a greenlet, which is supposed to retrieve data from the database, and this greenlet  must be awaited for the IO to happen. The warning is kind of "coroutine was never awaited" when using vanilla asyncio.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way around this. The expiry is intentional (see the final paragraph of [this section of the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint)) and doesn't seem to be configurable. You could cache the initial state and restore it an [expiry event listener](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.InstanceEvents.expire), and reset `expired`, but I don't know if this would be a safe course of action.